# Where do I place .sort()

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort words by their repetition rate with this code:

```
    from collections import Counter

text1 = str(input("Paste text here: "))

words1 = dict(Counter(text1.split()))

print(words1)
```

And the output looks something like this:

```
{'What': 1, 'is': 2, 'Lorem': 5, 'Ipsum?': 1, 'Ipsum': 3, 'simply': 1, 'dummy': 2, ...}
```

How do I sort it by decreasing order?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't semantically ordered data structures. Why don't you keep the `Counter`, and use [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)?

Comment: If you need sorted keys within a dict you are most likely using the wrong type to store your data. You could convert your dict to a list of tuples, e.g. ``[('What', 1), ('Lorem', 5), ...]`` and then sort the items within the list.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use `sorted`, which takes any iterable (including a dictionary) and produces a list sorted according to an arbitrary `key` function:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> text1 = "spam eggs spam spam eggs bacon spam toast spam bacon sausage eggs spam"
>>> words1 = Counter(text1.split())
>>> sorted(words1, key=words1.get, reverse=True)
['spam', 'eggs', 'bacon', 'toast', 'sausage']
```

`sort` is a `list` method, so to use `sort()` specifically you would need to convert the dictionary to a list using the `items()` function (which gives you tuples of the keys and values), and then sort according to the values:

```
>>> words1 = list(Counter(text1.split()).items())
>>> words1.sort(key=lambda i: -i[1])
>>> [i[0] for i in words1]
['spam', 'eggs', 'bacon', 'toast', 'sausage']
```

This is equivalent to calling `Counter.most_common`, which produces a list of the `items()` sorted by descending value:

```
>>> words1 = Counter(text1.split()).most_common()
>>> [i[0] for i in words1]
['spam', 'eggs', 'bacon', 'toast', 'sausage']
```

Comment: `Counter` already has a `.most_common` method, to retrieve the elements in decreasing order of frequency. Why use `sorted` instead?